# how to display drop-down in iphone, like in this image

Tags: iphone, drop-down-menu

hi
I want to display drop down menu like the one you see in this image http://callingcard.marigoholdings.com/Screenshots.html#1
 (below From and To)
How can i create that? Any good tutorial.
Best regards

Comment: Which image do you mean?

Comment: @Claus Fixed that. He probably cannot yet insert images.

Comment: @Anton yeah, You are right, As a new user at stackoverflow, i got the message of not being able to upload images yet. Lemme google for similar image, and share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that app is using a combination of a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and an [html select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). To do something similar would involve a solid bit of html and javascript hackery, but in essence would be:

1. Create a UIWebView and inject the appropriate HTML into it to make the dropdown.
2. User uses dropdown as if it was in mobile safari and picks something.
3. When you need it, you use a javascript call with `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to grab the value of the dropdown by id and pass it back to your code.

There are a few gotchas here, mainly with constructing the dropdown and the webview such that it's big enough to show the expanded dropdown but transparent to see under it when the dropdown is not expanded, it's not scrollable, and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use UIPicker for this purpose.This is used as a dropdown whereever needed in iPhone.

Please refer the link below

[How to create drop down list box for an iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717309/how-to-create-drop-down-list-box-for-an-iphone-app)

Thanks

Comment: yeah, i know that.. But UIPicker covers almost half of the screen. I wanna show it as a one row. And when it is tapped, it should display UIPicker
Thanks

Comment: So basically you want a picker which shows 1 row and after tapping on that row or the arrow button besides it,the picker has to be displayed.Ri8??

Comment: Use a button to display a single line and onclick of that button pop the UIPicker and populate that button again when a value is selected from the picker.

Comment: thank u so much Aditya... Now i try to do that... and will respond you when i am done

Comment: Thats the easiest and fastest way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a UIActionsheet might be better ... you could easy make a button to call the sheet.  Adding multiple buttons to the sheet transforms it into a table that you can scroll.