# How can we implement Dropdownlist functionality in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I know there is no any controls like Dropdownlist in iOS library but suppose we want to implement this type of functionality then how can I do this....

I do not want any code but just want to get suggestion from our peers...

So Let me know about how can I implement it in iPhone...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please check [this link][1].. It may be helpful to you.. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717309/how-to-create-drop-down-list-box-for-an-iphone-app Check [this link][2] also.. [2]:http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/iphone-development/custom-dropdown-list/

Comment: You can also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467029/how-to-create-dropdown-in-xcode/18952583#18952583

Answer (score 4):

I think UIPicker is generally the alternative to the drop down on iPhone, that's what pops up when you use a drop down in the web browser.

See [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) for further reference.