# How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have been working to create a UIAlertView in Swift, but for some reason I can't get the statement right because I'm getting this error:

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied
>   arguments

Here is how I have it written:

```
let button2Alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "message",
                     delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: nil)
```

Then to call it I'm using:

```
button2Alert.show()
```

As of right now it is crashing and I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: `UIAlertView` and `UIActionSheet` has been replaced by `UIAlertController` in iOS 8, have you looked at this?

Comment: Make sure the class that `self` belongs to adopts the protocol `UIAlertViewDelegate` (the recommended way to do this, in Swift, is with an extension).

Comment: @Adam: I have reverted your retagging. The [tag:swift3] tag is for *"questions directly related to changes in version 3 of Apple's Swift programming language."* And I don't think that *"If the answers make it clear that the problem in the question was caused by something other than what the asker thought, retagging is very helpful."* from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers applies here.

Comment: @MartinR I don't know how questions can be updated to show that there are answers that apply to a current version of Swift; there is a lot of old, useless stuff here and [swift] finds it all along with the useful. I don't feel strongly about this retag being reverted but I wish there was a definitive way to solve this problem. (I wish answers had tags.)

Answer (score 1008, accepted):

From the `UIAlertView` class:

> // UIAlertView is deprecated. Use **UIAlertController** with a
> preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

On iOS 8, you can do this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now `UIAlertController` is a single class for creating and interacting with what we knew as `UIAlertView`s and `UIActionSheet`s on iOS 8.

**Edit:** To handle actions:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    switch action.style{
    case .Default:
        print("default")
        
    case .Cancel:
        print("cancel")
        
    case .Destructive:
        print("destructive")
    }
}}))
```

**Edit for Swift 3:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Edit for Swift 4.x:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
    switch action.style{
        case .default:
        print("default")
        
        case .cancel:
        print("cancel")
        
        case .destructive:
        print("destructive")
        
    }
}))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Where did you see that UIAlertView is deprecated? I don't see that in the documentation?

Comment: Cmd + Click the `UIAlertView` class, and the comment is right on top of the class declaration.

Comment: I'll answer my own question for anyone else who's curious alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
                (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
                
                }))

Comment: What's the point of Cancel and Destructive cases since it will always be what you specified `.Default`?

Comment: Under what context, would the `completion` be not `nil` in `self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)` . Any samples?

Comment: @s1u, `completion` is just a block `(Void -> Void)?` that is executed when the view controller is done presenting.

Comment: I think your example is a confusing one or at least that I don't understand it usefulness. The style of the action is already `default`. There is no reason for you to `switch` over it in your closure. It will ALWAYS go to default. Can you make your example more meaningful so that we would know why the closure takes `action` as a parameter?

Comment: Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40894219/5175709) answer the switch case you did is **unnecessary**. The switch is only useful if the type, or title aren't hardcoded ie they are dynamic: *You might have a series of dynamic buttons so the titles are not hardcoded. And then the handler might need to pass the chosen title off to some other method call*

Comment: Can you add the SwiftUI version?

Answer (score 560):

## One Button

[image: One Button Screenshot]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showAlertButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## Two Buttons

[image: Two Button Alert Screenshot]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showAlertButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "UIAlertController", message: "Would you like to continue learning how to use iOS alerts?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## Three Buttons

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func showAlertButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // create the alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notice", message: "Lauching this missile will destroy the entire universe. Is this what you intended to do?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        // add the actions (buttons)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remind Me Tomorrow", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Launch the Missile", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

## Handling Button Taps

The `handler` was `nil` in the above examples. You can replace `nil` with a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to do something when the user taps a button. For example:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Launch the Missile", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { action in

    // do something like...
    self.launchMissile()

}))
```

## Notes

- Multiple buttons do not necessarily need to use different `UIAlertAction.Style` types. They could all be `.default`.
- For more than three buttons consider using an Action Sheet. The setup is very similar. [Here is an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991999/3681880)

Comment: is there any delegate property in UIAlertController? in UIAlertView there is a delegate property which we sometime set to self, Is there any nothing like this in UIAlertController?? I am New , please help me

Comment: Beautiful answer - Now how can we switch to a new view within the handler?

Answer (score 117):

You can create a UIAlert using the standard constructor, but the 'legacy' one seems to not work:

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
alert.title = "Alert"
alert.message = "Here's a message"
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Understood")
alert.show()
```

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

Comment: @Zorayr UIAlertController is only available from iOS 8 onwards, please also mention that when suggesting its use. There are situations where iOS7 support is still desired and people might miss the problem. Deprecation doesn't mean "don't ever use this anymore."

Comment: This works if your app is still targeting iOS 7. However, ideally UIAlertView should only be used when UIAlertController is not available. if NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") != nil { /* use UIAlertController * / } else { /* use UIAlertView * / }

Comment: UIAlertview() is now deprecated in iOS 9

Answer (score 50):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10

**Method 1 :**

**SIMPLE ALERT**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your title", message: "Your message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
     let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
     })
     alert.addAction(ok)
     let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
     })
     alert.addAction(cancel)
     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
})
```

**Method 2 :**

**ALERT WITH SHARED CLASS**

If you want Shared class style(Write once use every where)

```
import UIKit
class SharedClass: NSObject {//This is shared class
static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

    //Show alert
    func alert(view: UIViewController, title: String, message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        alert.addAction(defaultAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            view.present(alert, animated: true)
        })
    }

    private override init() {
    }
}
```

Now call alert like this in every ware

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, title: "Your title here", message: "Your message here")
```

**Method 3 :**

**PRESENT ALERT TOP OF ALL WINDOWS**

If you want to present alert on top of all views, use this code

```
func alertWindow(title: String, message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    
        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        alert2.addAction(defaultAction2)
    
        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Function calling

```
SharedClass.sharedInstance.alertWindow(title:"This your title", message:"This is your message")
```

**Method 4 :**

**Alert with Extension**

```
extension  UIViewController {

    func showAlert(withTitle title: String, withMessage message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        alert.addAction(ok)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

Now call like this

```
//Call showAlert function in your class
@IBAction func onClickAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showAlert(withTitle:"Your Title Here", withMessage: "YourCustomMessageHere")
}
```

**Method 5 :**

**ALERT WITH TEXTFIELDS**

If you want to add textfields to alert.

```
//Global variables
var name:String?
var login:String?

//Call this function like this:  alertWithTF() 
//Add textfields to alert 
func alertWithTF() {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Login", message: "Enter username&password", preferredStyle: .alert)
    // Login button
    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        // Get TextFields text
        let usernameTxt = alert.textFields![0]
        let passwordTxt = alert.textFields![1]
        //Asign textfileds text to our global varibles
        self.name = usernameTxt.text
        self.login = passwordTxt.text
        
        print("USERNAME: \(self.name!)\nPASSWORD: \(self.login!)")
    })
    
    // Cancel button
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })
    
    //1 textField for username
    alert.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter username"
        //If required mention keyboard type, delegates, text sixe and font etc...
        //EX:
        textField.keyboardType = .default
    }
    
    //2nd textField for password
    alert.addTextField { (textField: UITextField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
    
    // Add actions
    alert.addAction(loginAction)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

**Method 6:**

**Alert in SharedClass with Extension**

```
//This is your shared class
import UIKit

 class SharedClass: NSObject {

 static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

 //Here write your code....

 private override init() {
 }
}

//Alert function in shared class
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Now call directly like this

```
self.showAlert(title: "Your title here...", msg: "Your message here...")
```

**Method 7:**

**Alert with out shared class with Extension in separate class** for alert.

Create one new Swift class, and `import UIKit`. Copy and paste below code.

```
//This is your Swift new class file
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UIAlertController {
    class func alert(title:String, msg:String, target: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (result: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        })
        target.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now call alert function like this in all your classes (Single line).

```
UIAlertController.alert(title:"Title", msg:"Message", target: self)
```

How is it....

Comment: Perfekt! +1 Could you please add a method with an integrated timeout? Thanks!

Comment: @ Passe, sorry I can't understood, can please explain briefly.

Comment: I need an alertController which is presented until the 'OK' button is clicked or a timeout occurred. Something like method 6 or 7 but with an additional input variable 'timeout'.

Comment: extension UIViewController {
 func alertWithTime(title: String, msg: String, timeInterval:TimeInterval) {
 DispatchQueue.main.async {  let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false, block: { _ in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }) } else {// Fallback on earlier versions}}}}

Comment: Call like this self.alertWithTime(title: "Title", msg: "Message", timeInterval:3.0)//Display 3 seconds

Comment: Here this timer code can work from iOS 10 and higher versions.

Comment: If you mention timeInterval 0 in that case if you don't want to close alert, use if condition.  `if timeInterval != 0 {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false, block: { _ in
                        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }`

Comment: nice solutions. In method 2, "SharedClass.SharedInstance..." have to be "SharedClass.sharedInstance...".

Answer (score 20):

**Click of View**

```
@IBAction func testClick(sender: UIButton) {

  var uiAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  self.presentViewController(uiAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
   println("Click of default button")
  }))

  uiAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { action in
   println("Click of cancel button")
  }))

}
```

**Done with two buttons OK & Cancel**

Comment: very helpful for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you're targeting iOS 7 *and* 8, you need something like this to make sure you're using the right method for each version, because `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8, but `UIAlertController` is not available in iOS 7:

```
func alert(title: String, message: String) {
    if let getModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") { // iOS 8
        let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else { // iOS 7
        let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alert.delegate = self

        alert.title = title
        alert.message = message
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

        alert.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can save time and just use `UIAlertView` until you drop support for iOS 7. Apple won't reject your app for that.

Comment: Deprecation doesn't mean "don't use this" or that it would be the "wrong method", it just means it will not work later on. There's no need to specifically use UIAlertController on iOS8 if one just needs basic alerts. They will work as before. There are many APIs that have been deprecated in iOS4 or 5 and still work in iOS8. But of course apps targeting a higher iOS level should not use them and that's why there is a deprecation warning.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No, but it makes it clearer why you're doing what you're doing and makes it easier to remove support for deprecated methods when your minimum version is high enough to do so.

Answer (score 12):

With the protocol extensions of Swift 2, you can make a protocol that provides a default implementation to your view controllers:

ShowsAlert.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol ShowsAlert {}

extension ShowsAlert where Self: UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String = "Error", message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ShowsAlert {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showAlert(message: "Hey there, I am an error message!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. For Swift3 change 'presentViewController' to 'present'.

Answer (score 11):

Show UIAlertView in swift language :-

Protocol UIAlertViewDelegate

```
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "alertView", message: "This is alertView", delegate:self, cancelButtonTitle:"Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Done", "Delete")
alert.show()
```

Show UIAlertViewController in swift language :-

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter data in Text fields", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply do not provide otherButtonTitles in the constructor.

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: "Something
happened...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

alertView.show()
```

But I do agree with Oscar, this class is deprecated in iOS 8, so there won't be no use of UIAlertView if you're doing an iOS 8 only app. Otherwise the code above will work.

Answer (score 11):

**AlertView Swift 5 and above:-**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: LocalizedStringConstant.alert, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
     }))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 10):

For **SWIFT4**, I think, extending `UIViewController` and creating a reusable confirmation control is the most elegant way.

You can extend the `UIViewController` as below:

```
extension UIViewController {

func AskConfirmation (title:String, message:String, completion:@escaping (_ result:Bool) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { action in
        completion(true)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
        completion(false)
    }))
  }
}
```

Then you can use it anytime:

```
 AskConfirmation(title: "YOUR MESSAGE TITLE", message: "YOUR MESSAGE") { (result) in
        if result { //User has clicked on Ok

        } else { //User has clicked on Cancel

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I found this one,

```
var alertView = UIAlertView();
alertView.addButtonWithTitle("Ok");
alertView.title = "title";
alertView.message = "message";
alertView.show();
```

not good though, but it works :)

Update:

but I have found on header file as:

```
extension UIAlertView {
    convenience init(title: String, message: String, delegate: UIAlertViewDelegate?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles firstButtonTitle: String, _ moreButtonTitles: String...)
}
```

somebody may can explain this.

Comment: Apparently UIAlertView has been deprecated in iOS 8 and we now use UIAlertController with a preferred style of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert.

Comment: If you run an app that needs to be backwards compatible to iOS7.1 and you're writing it in Swift, the UIAlertController will crash the target device.  You need to support the legacy UIAlertViews for iOS7.

Comment: I think that it's not Swift that would cause a crash, but rather the fact that the UIAlertController is not available before iOS 8

Answer (score 7):

**For iOS 13 Xcode 11+ Swift 5.X**

`UIAlertController` can now provide Alerts as well as Action Sheets

**Alerts**

```
// First instantiate the UIAlertController

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                              message: "Message ?",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)


 // Add action buttons to it and attach handler functions if you want to 

 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Just Do It!", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe", style: .default, handler: nil))

// Show the alert by presenting it

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Note that it's is a fundamental nature for all action buttons to dismiss the alert view when tapped. The *`style` parameter is just for deciding the color* of the text (and some default order in which the buttons should appear which ofc can be changed)

A sample handler function could be

```
func handler(_ action: UIAlertAction) { 

   if action.title == 'Title' {
       // do stuff
   }

}
```

As a side note, I would say instead of making 3 different handlers you can just make 1 and trace back to the element which provoked it in the manner shown above
We can also check `alert.style` but that again we can have multiple `.default` styled actions , I wouldn't recommend that

**Action Sheets**

The explanation is similar because the main difference here is that ***an alert interrupts the user whereas an action sheet slides from the bottom in an iPhone*** and appears as a popover in an iPad

The Purpose of action sheets is to guide the users in deciding his actions based on their current state. So you gotta treat action sheets like crossroads !. There is generally no message and the title is rendered as caption sized text

```
let action = UIAlertController(title: "What do you want to do with the message",
                               message: nil,
                               preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

action.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)) 

for act in ["Save", "Post", "Discard"] {  
          action.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: act, style: .default, handler: nil))
}

self.present(action, animated: true)
```

The above code is going to work for an iPhone but ***will crash at runtime for an iPad*** because `UIPopoverPresentationController` is going to take charge of the alert and it won't be referencing anything at that time. So to avoid that you will have to provide the following chunk of code its mandatory

```
if let pop = action.popoverPresentationController {

     let v = sender as! UIView 
     pop.sourceView = v 
     pop.sourceRect = v.bounds
 }
```

Also in case of iPad tapping on anywhere outside the popover will dismiss it and the completion handler of `.cancel` action button will be called.

Hope that helps :) That being said, comment down below if you have any doubts

Comment: Self in the context of view controller

Answer (score 5):

```
    class Preview: UIViewController , UIAlertViewDelegate
    {
        @IBAction func MoreBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject)
        {
            var moreAlert=UIAlertView(title: "Photo", message: "", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "No Thanks!", otherButtonTitles: "Save Image", "Email", "Facebook", "Whatsapp" )
            moreAlert.show()
            moreAlert.tag=111;
        }

        func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int)
        {
            if alertView.tag==111
            {
                if buttonIndex==0
                {
                    println("No Thanks!")
                }
                else if buttonIndex==1
                {
                    println("Save Image")
                }
                else if buttonIndex == 2
                {
                    println("Email")
                }
                else if buttonIndex == 3
                {
                    println("Facebook")
                }
                else if buttonIndex == 4
                {
                    println("Whatsapp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just writing a lump of code is not very useful. When answering any question (specially an old question with several answers including an accepted answer) please write more than a piece of code. Please add an explanation of what your code does, how it answers the question and how it is different (or better) than the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

I have another trick. Suppose you have 5 classes where a logout alert to be applied. Try with swift class extension.

File- New- Swift class- Name it.

Add the following:

```
public extension UIViewController
{

    func makeLogOutAlert()
    {
        var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are You Sure to Log Out ? ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }))

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            refreshAlert .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))

        presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Implement using :  self.makeLogOutAlert(). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I have made a singleton class to make this convenient to use from anywhere in your app: https://github.com/Swinny1989/Swift-Popups

You can then create a popup with multiple buttons like this:

```
Popups.SharedInstance.ShowAlert(self, title: "Title goes here", message: "Messages goes here", buttons: ["button one" , "button two"]) { (buttonPressed) -> Void in
    if buttonPressed == "button one" { 
      //Code here
    } else if buttonPressed == "button two" {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

or popups with a single button like this:

```
Popups.SharedInstance.ShowPopup("Title goes here", message: "Message goes here.")
```

Comment: Thanks. I submit some issue there

Comment: Hey @Swinny89 Thanks so much man for sharing this solution with us! I got stuck with the closure thing and you just saved me!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

The following is a simple example of how to create a simple alert with one button with Swift 3.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title",
                              message: "Message",
                              preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
present(alert, animated: true)
```

In the above example the handle callback of the action has been omitted because the default behaviour of an alert view with one button is to disappear when the button is clicked.

Here is how to create another action, which could be added to the alert with "alert.addAction(action)". The different styles are .default, .destructive and .cancel.

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
    // Handle when button is clicked    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the following `UIAlertView` initialization code to compile without errors (I thing the last, varyadic part is tricky perhaps). But I had to make sure the class of `self` (which I am passing as the delegate) was adopting the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol for the compile errors to go away:

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(
                  title: "My Title",
                  message: "My Message",
                  delegate: self,
                  cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel",
                  otherButtonTitles: "OK"
                )
```

By the way, this is the error I was getting (as of Xcode 6.4):

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIAlertView' that accepts an
>   argument list of type '(title: String, message: String, delegate:
>   MyViewController, cancelButtonTitle: String, otherButtonTitles:
>   String)'

As others mentioned, you should migrate to UIAlertController if you can target iOS 8.x+. To support iOS 7, use the code above (iOS 6 is not supported by Swift).

Answer (score 4):

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Select Photo", message: "Select atleast one photo", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "From Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Default is pressed.....")
    }
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        print("Cancel is pressed......")
    }
    let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Click new", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Destructive is pressed....")

    }
    alertController.addAction(action1)
    alertController.addAction(action2)
    alertController.addAction(action3)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this simple extension with **n number** of buttons and associated actions swift4 and above

```
extension UIViewController {
    func popupAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actionTitles:[String?], actions:[((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?]) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        for (index, title) in actionTitles.enumerated() {
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: .default, handler: actions[index])
            alert.addAction(action)
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

you can use it like ,

```
self.popupAlert(title: "Message", message: "your message", actionTitles: ["first","second","third"], actions:[
            {action1 in
                //action for first btn click
            },
            {action2 in
                //action for second btn click
            },
            {action3 in
                //action for third btn click
            }, nil])
```

Comment: you please don't post duplicate answers. If you want edit your answer.

Comment: Excellent answer. This is what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Or just do this

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Saved Successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason it doesn't work because some value you passed to the function isn't correct. swift doesn't like Objective-C, you can put nil to arguments which are class type without any restriction(might be). Argument otherButtonTitles is defined as non-optional which its type do not have (?)at its end. so you must pass a concrete value to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBAction func Alert(sender: UIButton) {

    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Alert!"
    alertView.message = "Message"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

    alertView.show()

}
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to display an alertview

```
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello  Coders", message: "your alert message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close Alert", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Reference: [Swift Show Alert using UIAlertController](https://www.simplifiedios.net/ios-show-alert-using-uialertcontroller/)

Answer (score 3):

in xcode 9

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 4 : Simply create a extension to UIViewController as follows:

```
extension  UIViewController {        
    func showSuccessAlert(withTitle title: String, andMessage message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message,
                                  preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localized, style:
        UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now in your ViewController, directly call above function as if they are provided by UIViewController.

```
    yourViewController.showSuccessAlert(withTitle: 
      "YourTitle", andMessage: "YourCustomTitle")
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Answer (score 2):

try This.
Put Bellow Code In Button.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Your_Title_Text", message: "Your_MSG", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Your_Text", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

// Custom Class For UIAlertView

```
//MARK:- MODULES
import Foundation
import UIKit

//MARK:- CLASS
class Alert  : NSObject{

static let shared = Alert()

var okAction : AlertSuccess?
typealias AlertSuccess = (()->())?
var alert: UIAlertController?

/** show */
public func show(title : String?, message : String?, viewController : UIViewController?, okAction : AlertSuccess = nil) {

    let version : NSString = UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString
    if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)
        alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

            if let okAction = okAction {
                okAction()
            }
        }))
        viewController?.present(alert ?? UIAlertController(), animated:true, completion:nil);
    }
}

/** showWithCancelAndOk */
public func showWithCancelAndOk(title : String, okTitle : String, cancelTitle : String, message : String, viewController : UIViewController?, okAction : AlertSuccess = nil, cancelAction : AlertSuccess = nil) {
    let version:NSString = UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString;

    if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)

        alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

            if let cancelAction = cancelAction {
                cancelAction()
            }
        }))
        alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: okTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

            if let okAction = okAction {
                okAction()
            }
        }))
        viewController?.present(alert!, animated:true, completion:nil);
    }
}

/** showWithTimer */
public func showWithTimer(message : String?, viewController : UIViewController?) {

    let version : NSString = UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString
    if  version.doubleValue >= 8 {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle:.alert)
        viewController?.present(alert ?? UIAlertController(), animated:true, completion:nil)
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
            self.alert?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Use:-

```
Alert.shared.show(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "The internet connection appers to be offline.", viewController: self) //without ok action

Alert.shared.show(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "The internet connection appers to be offline.", viewController: self, okAction: {
                            //ok action
                        }) // with ok action

Alert.shared.show(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "The internet connection appers to be offline.", viewController: self, okAction: {
                            //ok action 
}, cancelAction: {
 //cancel action
}) //with cancel and ok action

Alert.shared.showWithTimer(message : "This is an alert with timer", viewController : self) //with timer
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a funny example in Swift:

```
private func presentRandomJoke() {
  if let randomJoke: String = jokesController.randomJoke() {
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title:nil, message:randomJoke, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Done", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil))
    presentViewController(alertController, animated:true, completion:nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a pretty simple function of AlertView in Swift :**

```
class func globalAlertYesNo(msg: String) {
        let alertView = UNAlertView(title: "Title", message: msg)

        alertView.messageAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        alertView.buttonAlignment  = UNButtonAlignment.Horizontal

        alertView.addButton("Yes", action: {

            print("Yes action")

        })

        alertView.addButton("No", action: {

            print("No action")

        })

        alertView.show()

    }
```

*You have to pass message as a String where you use this function.*

Answer (score 1):

The Old Way: UIAlertView

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
alertView.alertViewStyle = .Default
alertView.show()

// MARK: UIAlertViewDelegate

 func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
 switch buttonIndex {

    // ...
   }
  }
```

The New Way: UIAlertController

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default Style", message: "A standard alert.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
// ...
 }
 alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

 let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
// ...
 }
 alertController.addAction(OKAction)
 self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**on IOS 9, you can do this**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  // UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController 
  // title = title of the alert view.
  // message = Alert message you want to show.
  // By tap on "OK" , Alert view will dismiss.

 UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Enter Message here.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to the code you posted? As it is now, your answer does not really qualify as a good answer by SO rules.

Comment: alert view has changed now in swift 4.use alert controller

Answer (score 1):

Below is the reusable code for alert view and action sheet, Just write one line to show alert anywhere in application

```
class AlertView{

    static func show(title:String? = nil,message:String?,preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert,buttons:[String] = ["Ok"],completionHandler:@escaping (String)->Void){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: preferredStyle)

        for button in buttons{

            var style = UIAlertActionStyle.default
            let buttonText = button.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            if buttonText == "cancel"{
                style = .cancel
            }
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: button, style: style) { (_) in
                completionHandler(button)
            }
            alert.addAction(action)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let rootViewController = app.window?.rootViewController {
                rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        AlertView.show(title: "Alert", message: "Are you sure ?", preferredStyle: .alert, buttons: ["Yes","No"]) { (button) in
            print(button)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SwiftUI** on Swift 5.x and Xcode 11.x

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("A Button") {

                self.isShowingAlert.toggle()
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) { () -> Alert in
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Alert"),
                    message: Text("This is an alert"),
                    dismissButton:
                        .default(
                            Text("OK"),
                            action: {
                                print("Dismissing alert")
                            }
                        )
                )
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude this is swift ui that's not what's asked

Comment: Yes, but since we use StackOverflow as a documentation resource, I thought it could be useful to anyone looking for how to present notifications using SwiftUI. I remember having a hard time finding the answer to that, and thought I could contribute posting this here. I view the question like "how to present an alert in a Swift application" rather than "how to present UIAlert using exclusively UIKit".

Answer (score 1):

For above 13.0 version
Using SceneDelegate

For All Kind of Classes

```
static func showWindowAlert(alertMessage: String, inVC:UIViewController) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate
              else {
                return
              }
            sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController = inVC
            sceneDelegate.window?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1
        
            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: App_Name, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            })
            alert2.addAction(defaultAction2)
        
            sceneDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
            sceneDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }
```