# Action sheet programmatically

Tags: uiactionsheet, swift, ios8

Any one please help to create action sheet controller programmatically with xcode6 using swift language.

Comment: The important bit is the "include minimal example". What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 7):

The question appears to be too generic.

May be you could refer to [How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift)

This might help you get started.

A typical code for presenting UIActionSheet using swift would might like this:

```
        var myActionSheet =  UIAlertController(title: "Delete all data ?", message: "You may not be able to recover this back", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
            println("Deleting the data...")
        }))
    myActionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Permanently", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: { (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
            println("Deleting data permanently...")
        }))
    self.presentViewController(myActionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```