# Create a simple Alert in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

It looks like **alertstatus** cannot be used in swift.

Can you guys please help me implementing an alternative solution to the code below?

```
  [self alertStatus:@"Message!" :@"Alert title" :0];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try with following code

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
alert.title = "Title"
alert.message = "My message"
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
alert.show()
```

But in **iOS 8**

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. So use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`. it should be

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

XCODE 10, IOS 12 And Swift 4 and above :

**1. simple alert view with no action on buttons in an alert.**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Something Went Wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

**2. Alert with actions on ok and cancel button:**

```
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Punch Out", message: "You Will Will Punch Out", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Handle Ok logic here")
   }))
        
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
            refreshAlert .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }))

    self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

*For more customization Refer to this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876884/6550949)*

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in 3 lines as such. Make sure to add the "OK" button or "Action" which will help dismiss the alert or else you will end up with the screen frozen on the alert

```
    let myMessage = "This is an alert"

    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: myMessage, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 iOS 10

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since edit queue is full, here is the accepted answer updated:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
present(alert, animated: true)
```