# Swift: Attaching instance variable to view controller

Tags: swift

if i have a `ViewController`, which has an instance `ShowAlert`. `showAlert` will show an alert controller, but is there any way the instance `showAlert` can know about who instantiated it? i.e. is there any way not to pass `self` to `ShowAlert`'s instance variable `viewController` and instead infer it by `parent` or something similar? should i somehow be delegating this, instead?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var showAlert = ShowAlert()

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showAlert.viewController = self
        showAlert.now()
    }
}

class ShowAlert: NSObject {

    var viewController: UIViewController!

    func now() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        viewController.showViewController(alert, sender: self)
    }

}
```

thanks -

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594238/swift-how-to-pass-a-view-controllers-reference-to-a-sub-uiview-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure instead of:

```
func now() {
```

do:

```
func now(parentVC : UIViewController ){
  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    parentVC.showViewController(alert, sender: self)
}
```

and you can call it like:

```
showAlert.now(self)
```