# UIAlertViewDelegate clickedButtonAtIndex is never called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is the controller I implemented for running on iOS7:

```
import UIKit


@objc(StartViewController)
class StartViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  }



  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let confirm:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "sdfsdf", message: "sfsff3333", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "cancel")
    confirm.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.Default
    confirm.show()
  }


  // MARK: UIAlertViewDelegate


  func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    println("buttonIndex: "+buttonIndex)
  }

  func alertViewCancel(alertView: UIAlertView) {
    println("cancel")

  }
}
```

It turns out that none of the functions from `UIAlertViewDelegate` is ever called even if I set the delegate correctly to self.

When I click on one of the buttons in the alert dialog I got the following output in the console:

```
0x796d4984
```

**What do I have to do to make the `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods being called?**

Edit: I also did:

```
confirm.delegate = self
```

This does not help.

Comment: Using your code only, I can see 'buttonIndex' output! Strange!

Comment: check this link plz
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift

Comment: @aBilal17 Which part. I need iOS7 not iOS8?

Comment: As @SohilR.Memon, if I run your code  I can see 'buttonIndex' output

Answer (score 0):

When you're making the `alertView`, do `confirm.delegate = self` (assuming `confirm` is your `UIAlertView`.

Comment: I did this. Does not help.

Comment: @confile very odd. Try making a new project, or doing a clean build?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line: `println("buttonIndex: "+buttonIndex)`

It must be like this:

```
println("buttonIndex: \(buttonIndex)")
```

Comment: In the question you say that the method is never called, this could be tracked with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Try, doing this. I think, the reason is you haven't assigned the delegate to self(your controller).

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let confirm:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "sdfsdf", message: "sfsff3333", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "cancel")
    confirm.delegate=self;
    confirm.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.Default
    confirm.show()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try UIAlertController for iOS 8 and UIAlertView for iOS 7. Do something like this:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0"))
{
  alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"aa" message:@"asdadad"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
    else
   {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController    alertControllerWithTitle:@"aca" message:@"asdfaf" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {

                               }];

    [alertController addAction:okAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```