# Alert action handler

Tags: ios, alert

I have an alert action with calling handler:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://number")!)}))
```

Now I want one more action that will call my function, something like this:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in myFunc() )}))
```

But it shows an error and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Help! Thanks!

Comment: can u post which error?

Comment: first: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' after myFunc

Comment: second: when i add ";" it says Expected expression

Comment: Follow this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you had an extra closing parentheses.

Replace the following line

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in myFunc() )}))
```

with

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in myFunc()}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had used extra closing bracket.

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in myFunc()}))
```