# How can I add an alert view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I would like to be able to add an alert view to my login screen that says Incorrect Username/ Password when the info submitted is incorrect. I am using Swift 2. I'm still new to learning code and I am unsure how to add this action.

Comment: See the answer in the following thread (`UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift

Comment: Take a look at this, i've written a small repo to do this for you. https://github.com/Swinny1989/iOS-Swift-Popups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code to display the alert:

```
func wrongLogin(input: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect", message: "The \(input) is wrong. Try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    //add a cancel button
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    // Show it

        showViewController(alert, sender: self)
    }
```

Then when calling it just pass in if it's the username or the password.

You can do that like this `wrongLogin("password")` or `wrongLogin("username")`

For further info see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/%E2%80%A6).

Hope that helps, Julian.