# IOS create UIAlertViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm working on a ViewController with code (no storyboard). I'm trying to add and AlertController

I have declare propery in .m

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIAlertController *alertController;
```

And init in `loadview` method

```
//alertviewController
    _alertController = [[UIAlertController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

And call the alertview in `viewDidLoad`:

```
_alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error display content" message:@"Error connecting to server, no local database" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                LandingPageViewController *viewController = [[LandingPageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //            viewController.showNavBarBackButton = YES;
                [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].rootViewController cPushViewController:viewController];
}];
[_alertController addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:_alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I dont' know why the alert is not showing up. Some thing wrong with my code. How to set up and call `alertViewController` programmatically?

Comment: Hi tried but there is error no visible interface for 'UIAlertController' declares the selector 'show'.    [_alertController show];

Comment: Remove this line `_alertController = [[UIAlertController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];` I'm not sure if that will fix the problem, but it's not needed, especially not in `loadView`, (did you mean `viewDidLoad`?)

Comment: try calling this alert in viewDidAppear

Comment: Hi i put the calling code in viewdidAppear the alert show up but crash with this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <StampCollectiblesMainViewController: 0x7b58d110>.'

Comment: it probably crashes on the button tap. which means make sure the alert dismisses and then the push takes place. call the push after delay

Comment: are you testing with the simulator or with a real device and what is the ios version

Comment: I call the method by putting all the creation and call in viewdidappear. but can not call in viewdidload. i'm working with simulator ios 9.3

Comment: Have you put any breakpoints into your code to follow the execution path and make sure that what you think is happening is actually happening.

Comment: I thinks the problem is that can not call present view controller in viewdidload. If i put the call in other place everything working fine!

Comment: Did you try checking out the new Documentation feature of Stackoverflow? This is extensively covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/874/uialertcontroller/2949/alert-views-with-uialertcontroller#t=201608020610222402166).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
- (void)logoutButtonPressed
{
     UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                 message:@"Are You Sure Want to Logout!"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    //Add Buttons

    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Yes"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    //Handle your yes please button action here
                                    [self clearAllData];
                                }];

    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   //Handle no, thanks button
                               }];

    //Add your buttons to alert controller

    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [alert addAction:noButton];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: hi where to call the [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil]; seem can not call in viewdidload

Comment: Hi it working when i create separate method and call in viewdidload but there a warning in console: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Comment: where r u performing ur alert controller, it may be button click or on some method, use above complete code in one method and call it in ur desire place. hope u got it

Comment: Hi my purpose is when user come to the viewcontroller the app will check whether coredata has record or not. if not and there is no internet connection . the app will show an error "no databae no internet connection" and move to home page!

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh it is not good to have alert view controller in viewDidLoad. u can check after view get loaded

Comment: Hi so where is good place to put it when user come to that viewcontroller?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh check here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller

Comment: Hi I found it only working good when we put in viewDidAppear. Everything seem working fine when move code to show UIalertViewController in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 7):

In Xcode 9.4.1

Create alert function globally and use every where.

```
//Alert function
- (void) showAlertMsg:(UIViewController *)viewController title:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {

    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : title
                                                                    message : message
                                                             preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          { }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });

}
```

Call like this in your required place.

Import that class and create instance

```
//Ex:
GlobalClassViewController *gcvc = [[GlobalClassViewController alloc]init];

//Call alert function with instance
[gcvc showAlertMsg:self title:@"" message:placeholderText];
```

[How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift/51876884#51876884)

Comment: The dispatch_async helped me get past some issues where my alerts weren't appearing because they were inadvertently created on view which were going out of scope.

Comment: The dispatch_async is necessary in iOS13+ with UISplitViewController on iPad (no scenes, no Storyboards). It is not required in iOS12 and lower. UI just locks up without showing the alert otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

And in 
**Swift >=3**:

```
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Some Error",
                                               message: "Pleas confirm?",
                                               preferredStyle: .alert)

  let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

  self?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: hi so where is the place to place the code whenever user come to that viewcontroller and app has finished checked for some logic (for example no coredata to show?)

Comment: It's up to you, you can put it in viewDidLoad if you'd like it to be displayed when the user comes to that view or you can have it fired on a certain button press via IBAction

Comment: Hi i found put on view did load not working for alertViewController. Need to be in viewDidAppear

Comment: Nice catch, that will work or it should also work as an IBAction

Answer (score 0):

Create global Alert controller that is accessible in all view controllers using extension.

Create an extension of `UIViewController` with your function to display alert with required parameter arguments.

```
extension UIViewController {

      func displayalert(title:String, message:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


      }
}
```

Now call this function from your view controller:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.displayalert(title: <String>, message: <String>)
    }
}
```