# If <UIAlertViewDelegate> is deprecated, how can I make my Alert button to do an action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertcontroller

We used to use `UIAlertViewDelegate` in `ViewController.h` to make our custom Alert button to do an action, like pressing the Play Again button in the alert window makes the game restart.

How do we do this with `UIAlertController`, the replacement class for `UIAlertView`?

I read this document bellow provided by Apple and didn't see a delegate method mentioned. Does it mean we don't do that anymore?

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: have a loot at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38703189/2522603

Comment: Imran, thank you so much for this. It helped a lot!

Comment: welcome you can upvote it, if you like my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First add `UIAlertController`
- Then Add `UIAlertAction`
- Then add that `action` to your `alert controller`.

like below.

```
UIAlertController *myalert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"your title" message:@"your messate" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *myaction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"you title" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        //your action here
    }];


    [myalert addAction:myaction];
    [self presentViewController:myalert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: "//your action here" part is especially made the point for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As it sounds like you found out, `UIAlertView` is deprecated (beginning in iOS 8), and so is `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

You're supposed to use `UIAlertController` instead. `UIAlertController` uses a different method for handling user taps on buttons. In `UIAlertController` you add `UIAlertAction` objects to your alert controller.

A `UIAlertAction` takes a block of code that gets called when the user triggers that action. Instead of setting up a delegate that listens for messages in a protocol, you pass a handler block (closure) to each button action that you set up. It's a different way of solving the same problem.

@AnuradhS gave sample code showing hot to set it up.