# How to call an action after an alert closed in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uialertview

I have a subclass of UILabel called AlertLabel

AlertLabel.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AlertLabel : UILabel
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
  - (void)alertTitle:(NSString *)string;
@end
```

AlertLabel.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)alertTitle:(NSString *)string {
  self.text = string;
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeLabelFromView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)removeLabelFromView {
  [self removeFromSuperview];
}
```

In a viewcontroller called AVController, it can be called like this

```
 - (void)buttonClick:(UIButton *)button {
  AlertLabel *alert = [[AlertLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 30)];
  [alert alertTitle:@"Success"];
  [self.view addSubview:alert];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(callThisActionAfterAlertClosed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }

 - (void)callThisActionAfterAlertClosed {
  NSLog(@"works");
 }
```

It works, but it doesn't work perfectly, especially the second NSTimer(call the `callThisActionAfterAlertClosed`), sometime, the alertlabel doesn't close, but the second nstimer function begins.

It should be popup, automatically close after one second, call another function after closed, all steps like this are performed in an orderly manner.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you can take ref from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702269/ios-create-uialertviewcontroller-programmatically/38703189)

Comment: Are you trying to create or mimic an UIAlertController?