# How to access Customalertview objective C instancetype method in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, swift3, uialertcontroller

```
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
    NSMutableArray *otherButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *arg = otherButtonTitles; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [otherButtonsArray addObject:arg];
    }
    va_end(args);

    if (POST_iOS8) {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >70120
        self = [super init];
        alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        int buttonIndex = 0;
        if(cancelButtonTitle)
        {
            CustomAlertAction *cancelAction =[CustomAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancelButtonTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                if(delegate)
                {
                    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
                        [delegate alertView:self clickedButtonAtIndex:((CustomAlertAction*)action).buttonIndex];
                    }
                }
            }];
            [cancelAction setButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
            [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
            buttonIndex++;
        }

        for (NSString *otherButton in otherButtonsArray)
        {
            CustomAlertAction *otherAction =[CustomAlertAction actionWithTitle:otherButton style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                if(delegate)
                {
                    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]) {
                        [delegate alertView:self clickedButtonAtIndex:((CustomAlertAction*)action).buttonIndex];
                    }
                }
            }];
            [otherAction setButtonIndex:buttonIndex];
            [alertController addAction:otherAction];
            buttonIndex++;
        }

#endif

    }
    else
    {
        self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];
        for (NSString *otherButton in otherButtonsArray)
        {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:otherButton];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

I have designed to class to have common code along project to show alert with title, message, a button titles, Which is working fine with objective C code.

But I want to utilise the same code in one of my swift project, am unable to call this method and provide other button titles

Note that am unable to access like

```
CustomAlertView.initWithTitle......
```

Comment: `CustomAlertView.initWithTitle......`

Comment: i tried it's not working @Mr.UB

Comment: This initializer is from UIAlertView, which is deprecated since iOS 9. Maybe it's better to just go for UIAlertController instead? From this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24022764/1638166 it would seem that this initializer for UIAlertView never worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OtherButton1", "OtherButton2")
```

I'm not sure what `CustomAlertView` is.  If that's your class, replace `UIAlertView` with `CustomAlertView` in the initializer.

`otherButtonTitles` is a comma separated list of Strings:

```
public convenience init(title: String, message: String, delegate: UIAlertViewDelegate?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles firstButtonTitle: String, _ moreButtonTitles: String...)
```

You don't need to use a singleton like in Rahul's answer.

Assuming your `CustomAlertView.h` file looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomAlertView : UIAlertView

-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...;

@end
```

You can import `CustomAlertView.h` into your bridging header and initialize the class like this in Swift 3:

```
CustomAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "Other1", "Other2")
```

Comment: CustomAlertView is an objective C class and not an swift class

Comment: @Vinodh can you post the full interface and implementation of the class?

Comment: @Vinodh what happens if you use the code I posted above and replace `UIAlertView` with `CustomAlertView`?

Comment: please read my question carefully , i have a class in obj c and i want access the class in method to show alert . Please let me know how to do it .

Comment: @Vinodh Right, so the first step would be to import that class through a bridging header.  The second step would be to call CustomAlertView like I posted above: `CustomAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OtherButton1", "OtherButton2")`

Comment: @Vinodh see my updated answer for Swift 3.  You don't need to use a singleton like in Rahul's answer.

Comment: @JAL I think category class is no need to use a singleton, but  `CustomAlertView` is not a category class. So, @Vinodh use of singleton like my answer.

Comment: @Rahul `CustomAlertView` is not a category, it is a subclass of `UIAlertView`.

Comment: @JAL Yeah, my side doesn't work. So, How to access this method.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Vinodh, you apparently don't understand how the bridging works. Once you have done what @JAL suggests (adding your Objective-C class's header to the bridging header) you can use the `init` from Swift by calling `CustomAlertView(title: ...`. Don't try to call `CustomAlertView.initWithTitle......` that doesn't make sense in Swift (init methods look just differently and the bridging adapts them accordingly). That would call a class method called `init...`, which, obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

`CustomAlertView.h` file

```
@interface CustomAlertView : UIAlertView

+(CustomAlertView *)sharedInstance;

//your method
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title ...

@end
```

`CustomAlertView.m` file

```
#import "CustomAlertView.h"

@implementation CustomAlertView

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (CustomAlertView *) sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;

    __strong static CustomAlertView * _sharedObject = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedObject;
}

//your method
-(instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title ...
```

& then call your method...

`CustomAlertView.sharedInstance().initWithTitle` ......

Comment: There is no reason to use a singleton to expose this method to Swift.

Comment: Reason is instance method not a direct access to another class.

Comment: Re your edit on my answer: `UIAlertView` works perfectly fine in with Swift 3.0, and is your only option if you are targeting iOS 7.x.  Did you even try my code?

Comment: And the instance method *is* accessible if placed in the header properly like in my answer, which is what I'm assuming the OP is doing as well.

Comment: `swift 3.0 deprecated UIAlertView class` this is horribly incorrect.  `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 9, **not** Swift 3.0. See the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertview).

Comment: I don't think you understand how deprecations work.  Xcode doesn't cause the deprecation, the iOS SDK level does.  Change the Deployment Target of an app in Xcode 8 to 7.0, you will no longer get a warning that `UIAlertView` is deprecated.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but I,m using ios9 to a higher level SDK so, a warning is thrown....