# how to display alert windows one by one SWift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift, and I have questions regarding how to present Alert Window one by one after the user clicks the button(dismiss). So I could have the second the window pops out right after users click the button to dismiss the alert? So far,
I tried I can't display them together by trying:

```
  self.createAlert(title: " 1", message: "1")
  self.createAlert(title: " 2",message: "2")
```

And I would get error message:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f9e4380b800> on <UITabBarController: 0x7f9e43059000> (from <IFTTT.HomePageViewController: 0x7f9e41c17be0>) which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7f9e4280b000>.
```

Can someone introduce me to some techniques to solve this? Like a boolean function to know if the last window is closed or something more efficient. Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user taps a button in an alert to dismiss it, you get called in that button's action handler:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
    // what goes here?
}))
```

The code in "what goes here?" is called *after* the alert is dismissed, so that is your chance to present another alert immediately.