# Is there an iOS equivalent of NSRunAlertPanel?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to, when a button is pressed, a small menu comes up, like NSRunAlertPanel in Cocoa. It is like in iOS, when you press reset, it gives you options to continue, or go back. Image:[image: menu]

How do I do this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating iPhone Pop-up Menu Similar to Mail App Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911137/creating-iphone-pop-up-menu-similar-to-mail-app-menu)

Comment: @thelaws This is not a dupe of that question, since the answers there recommend `UIActionSheet`, which is deprecated.

Comment: @AaronBrager The very next answer links the UIAlertController.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, the answer to this is UIActionSheet in iOS < 8 and UIAlertController for iOS >= 8. Easier to grab a library that's abstracted that away for you; these look good.

Objective-C: [MSAlertController for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/msalertcontroller)

Swift: [SimpleAlert for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/simplealert)