# UiAlertview updating to UiAlertCOntroller advice

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode7.3

im sure new to coding and have been using the following code:

```
let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
            alertView.message = "Please enter Username and Password"
            alertView.delegate = self
            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertView.show()
        } else {
```

However Xcode 7.3 tells me that uialertview is now deprecated and whats me to put in UiAlertController however when i attempt it, i can never get it right.

If anyone could help me rewrite this i would be very grateful!

JackDK

Comment: "however when i attempt it, i can never get it right." - What do you mean by "I can never get it right"? Are you getting errors?

Comment: This question has been answered and thoroughly explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276503/where-to-find-a-clear-explanation-about-swift-alert-uialertcontroller